# How to combine the data of the same object in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

We know that there is the possibility of caterpillar becoming butterfly and tadpole becoming frog. The weight data is exclusive for the same name with different type (at least one is equal to zero in the same column).
How can I combine the data for the same name as the new dataframe (only save the newest type if exist) as below.

```
old_df = {'name':  ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e'],
        'type': ['tiger', 'caterpillar', 'butterfly', 'dolphin', 'tadpole', 'frog', 'dog'],
        'month1_weight': ['33', '0', '0', '59', '3', '0', '0'],
        'month2_weight': ['0', '0', '20', '65', '0', '10', '2'],
        }
old_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(old_df)
```

```
old dataframe:
name      type         month1_weight  month2_weight
a         tiger        33             0
b         caterpillar  0              0
b         butterfly    0              20
c         dolphin      59             65
d         tadpole      3              0
d         frog         0              10
e         dog          0              2

new dataframe:
name      type         month1_weight  month2_weight
a         tiger        33             0
b         butterfly    0              20
c         dolphin      59             65
d         frog         3              10
e         dog          0              2
```

Comment: please provide code  or the minimal data  frame under `pd` , see here mode details before post : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
new_dataframe = (
    old_dataframe.groupby("name")
    .agg({
        "type": "last",
        "month1_weight": lambda s: s.astype(int).sum().astype(str),
        "month2_weight": lambda s: s.astype(int).sum().astype(str)})
    .reset_index()
)

print(new_dataframe)
```

This prints:

```
  name       type month1_weight month2_weight
0    a      tiger            33             0
1    b  butterfly             0            20
2    c    dolphin            59            65
3    d       frog             3            10
4    e        dog             0             2
```